# What does this script do exactly?

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I have been trying to understand how https://rblx.trade/catalog/deals (a site that tracks roblox's catalog in real time and communicates changes to the client) communicates with the client. For this I have been inspecting the site and saw this script which I assume is the one that communicates new data to the client.

```
<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">
                {
                  "props":{
                    "pageProps":{
                      "title":"Roblox Catalog Deals","meta":{"description":"Get the best deals and snipes on Roblox limited items with our deals page! Also turn on notifications to get notified immediately whenever an item gets put up for sale for a cheap price on the Roblox catalog!"}
                      },
                      "__N_SSG":true},
                      "page":"/catalog/deals","query":{},"buildId":"WlqGtyKoC3mZ3T4hTYU5G","runtimeConfig":{
                      "isStaging":false,"api":{"url":"https://rblx.trade","proxyFrontend":false},"sentry":{"dsn":"https://cbbd6a053f7a4d8b8a182804421dddad@sentry.rblxtrade.com/3","tracesSampleRate":0.01}
                      },"isFallback":false,"gsp":true,"scriptLoader":[]
                }
    </script>
```

The problem is do not know how what it does and how it works as I do not know javascript. I searched somewhat how the script type works and what dns means, but thats it. Any help understanding what this scripts does would be wonderful

Comment: This isn’t a script. It’s a JSON snippet that doesn’t do anything on its own. It gets read elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not completely Javascript, as you can see in the type `type="application/json"` its [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), JSON is a notation to write objects in javascript. The script does not do anything by its own, just define a structure of information. Probably the logic that uses this information is somewhere else

Comment: So what does it do exactly? I'm assuming it holds the information the browser receives from the server, but how do I access that information after its given then?

Comment: Be aware that some pages try to prevent people from figuring them out. There probably are more scripts on the page, so see if any contains any code (functions, calls etc) from the browser press F12 to open the developer console and go the sources tab, there you will see all the scripts loaded and you can set breakpoints so the browser will stop if the line of code you are marking is excecuted. Very Cool!